# GTALK Support XMPP Personal Eventing Protocol

Tags: windows-phone-7, xmpp, google-talk

Anybody please clarify whether gtalk supports PEP(Personal Eventing Protocol- PubSub mechanism). Because in my WP7 app getting error as feature not implemented.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<iq from="msankeshwari@gmail.com/phoneFC07C39F" id="dcc3e8ea-5a40-4401-8843-9db4dd682b78" type="set">
<pubsub xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub">
    <publish node="http://jabber.org/protocol/geoloc">
        <item id="lastlocation">
            <geoloc xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/geoloc">
                <lat>47.64483</lat>
                <lon>-122.141197</lon>
                <acurracy>0</acurracy>
                <timestamp>2012-09-03T18:52:24.592+05:30</timestamp>
            </geoloc>
        </item>
    </publish>
</pubsub>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine if GTALK supports PEP or not, you need to refer [Determining Support](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html#support) section of Personal Eventing Protocol (XEP-0163). As per the specs I sent following  stanza to my own bare jid:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="get" from="jabberxmpplibrary@gmail.com/jaxl#0482f1a54bd2b72a91a384663b1f14ba" to="jabberxmpplibrary@gmail.com" id="3">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"></query>
</iq>
```

and received following response stanza:

```
<iq to="jabberxmpplibrary@gmail.com/jaxl#0482f1a54bd2b72a91a384663b1f14ba" from="jabberxmpplibrary@gmail.com" id="3" type="result">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info">
        <identity category="account" type="registered" name="Google Talk User Account"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/>
        <feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/>
        <feature var="msgoffline"/>
    </query>
</iq>
```

which indicates google-talk doesn't support PEP since server didn't return an identity of pubsub/pep on behalf of the account.